Tailwind focus-bg-customColor does not work on ios
<button
 class="py-2 bg-white border-solid border-1 border-black rounded-md focus:bg-focusBlue 
 focus:text-[#2C5DE5]"
 type="button"
 data-number={button_content}
>
   <%= button_content %>
</button>

The following button works great on Firefox and Chrome, but fails to show focus on iOS and MacOS safari, any ideas?

This question is similar to: Safari: focus event doesn't work on button element. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not a tailwind or custom color issue. Safari just won't give focus when clicking on buttons by their design. You can see that if you tab onto the button the focus will work.
